# Grid thumbnail expanding to fullscreen on click and transitioning to new page

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, animation

I'm trying to understand how [this website](http://www.johnsonbanks.co.uk/) achieves this effect where if I click on a thumbnail, the text disappears and the thumbnail expands to fit the screen and display a post.

I've been trying to google a variety of combinations on how to describe the effect - grid, thumbnail, zoom, magnify, click, expand, fullscreen, etc. - but I've had no luck in finding tutorials.

I also tried using the Chrome DevTools animations / elements inspector to try to understand exactly what elements are changing but I can't seem to figure it out. I can see that the post content goes into a div with class "feed" that originally has 0px but I don't see where the actual animation is happening, when the thumbnail actually expands in size.

Any help with how to implement this transition effect on a very general level or just how to use the developer tools to figure this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: the divs are just scaling + opacity

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve this effect.
But of you use Chrome Devtools and inspect the website you can see it uses 3D-transforms on many elements.

My guess is that the website uses some Javascript in combination with 3D-transforms. You can achieve very powerfull animations with just using CSS.

You can see a quick and dirty example demonstrating a simple transform down below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.scale-div').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });

});
```

```css
html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

div{
height:100px;
width:200px;
background-color:red;
transition:transform .5s ease;
}

.active{
  transform:scale(3);
  transition:transform .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scale-div">
</div>
```